# Using Office365 Excel array formulas, how can YTD totals be reset to zero for each new person?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, array-formulas

Given a list of names, months, and an amount for each month, how can a YTD total column be calculated for each person without changing the order of the data?  For each person, the data is in month order where the next record for that person is the same month or a later month.

[image]

You can see where my formula works, except it accumulates everyone together.  Need the YTD amount to be specific to the person (see the desired results section).

The formula is not resetting for each person:

```
=LET(data,A4:C12, name,CHOOSECOLS(data, 1), amt,CHOOSECOLS(data, 3),
    calc,   LAMBDA(a, v, a + v),
    ytdAmt, SCAN(0, amt, calc),
    resp,   HSTACK(name, ytdAmt),
resp )
```

| Data |  |  |  | Desired Result |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Name | Month | Amt |  | Name | YTD |
| Joe | 1 | 100 |  | Joe | 100 |
| Joe | 2 | 100 |  | Joe | 200 |
| Sandy | 2 | 300 |  | Sandy | 300 |
| Julie | 3 | 400 |  | Julie | 400 |
| Tom | 1 | 100 |  | Tom | 100 |
| Sandy | 2 | 200 |  | Sandy | 500 |
| Sandy | 2 | 100 |  | Sandy | 600 |
| Tom | 5 | 100 |  | Tom | 200 |
| Joe | 2 | 100 |  | Joe | 300 |

Using Excel version 2304.

Comment: I feel like all you need is a simple [SUMIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b). Use this in cell F4 and copy down: `=SUMIF(A$4:A4,E4,C$4:C4)`

Comment: @ciso next time, please try provide the sample data in Table Markdown format, it helps to reproduce the scenario. You can use: [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), just copy your data from Excel, past it there, generate the table, and copy it back to the question, leaving a blank line with the previous paragraph. Thanks

Comment: @davidleal  Will do.  Thank you for the suggestion on how.

Comment: @tigeravatar you can use `SUMIFS/SUMIF` as follows: =`=SUMIFS(C$2:C2, A$2:A2,A2)`, and drag it down, but I prefer in general array formulas. They have less maintenance effort and you can combine several results in one call, like in this example. Using the previous formula will require to maintain the list of names as a second formula. With an array solution you can use `HSTACK` and have everything in a single call. Obviously assuming no Excel version constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, it spills the entire result:

```
=LET(A,A2:A10, C,C2:C10, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)),
 HSTACK(A, MAP(A,seq, LAMBDA(n,i,SUM(FILTER(C, (A=n) * (seq<=i)))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

On each iteration of `MAP` it filters the values of column **C** by the current name (`n`) and all previous rows, then sum it. Finally `HSTACK` to return the names and the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MAP()` Function:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
    x, A4:A12,
    y, C4:C12,
    HSTACK(
        x,
        MAP(
            x,
            y,
            LAMBDA(a, b,
                LET(
                    c, A4,
                    d, C4,
                    SUMIF(
                        a:c,
                        a,
                        b:d
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

[image]

---

```
=LET(_data,A4:C12,
_name,INDEX(_data,,1),
_amt,INDEX(_data,,3),
_ytdTotal,LAMBDA(_names,_amt,LET(_firstName,A4,_firstAmt,C4,SUMIF(_firstName:_names,_names,_amt:_firstAmt))),
VSTACK({"Name","Amt"},HSTACK(_name,MAP(_name,_amt,_ytdTotal))))
```

---

Without hard-coding any cell addresses except the data:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E4`

```
=LET(d, A4:C12,x, INDEX(d,,1),y,INDEX(d,,3),
    HSTACK(x,MAP(x,y,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c, INDEX(x,1),d, INDEX(y,1),SUMIF(a:c,a,b:d))))))
```

---

Comment: Both work, but David Leal's solution doesn't require hard-coding as many addresses (A4 & C4).    Very much appreciate the work though.  It helps everyone get up to speed on the new Excel.

Comment: If you don't like about the hard-coding you can do it like this way: `=LET(x, A4:A12,y, C4:C12,
    HSTACK(x,MAP(x,y,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c, INDEX(x,1),d, INDEX(y,1),SUMIF(a:c,a,b:d))))))`

Comment: Sorry, but where in here is `A1`, `A2` and `A3` are included --> `=LET(x, A4:A12,y, C4:C12,     HSTACK(x,MAP(x,y,LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c, INDEX(x,1),d, INDEX(y,1),SUMIF(a:c,a,b:d))))))` and neither `A:C` nor `B:D` is hardcoded ? those are variables? how come they are hard coded? not really clear?

Comment: @ciso btw my version is `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16505.20000) 64-bit `

Comment: Usually the `:` notation inside array LAMBDA functions give problems. We have seen this in several questions here. Not always the same workaround to overcome it. I was trying for this case and I could not make it works I got `#VALUE!`. That’s the reason I try to avoid it combined with LAMBDA function. That is my experience. I hope it will be fixed in the future or recent version.

Comment: worth to mention @MayukhBhattacharya I tested it with my Excel version (Excel for Web) and it works. I tested for `SUMIF`and `SUMIFS`: `=LET(A,A2:A10, C,C2:C10, HSTACK(A, MAP(A,C, LAMBDA(ai,ci,SUMIFS(INDEX(C,1):ci,INDEX(A,1):ai,ai)))))` even without using a local variable (that was usually one of the workaround we used), but it doesn't work for my desktop version: Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise version 2304 (Build 16327.20248) same version as the OP